# Meaning of って in this sentence

Tags: meaning, usage

I was watching Tatami Galaxy and one of the characters said the following sentence:

「どうせあなたはどんな道を選んだって今みたいな有様になっちまうんだ。」

I know the other uses of って but I'm confused here. Going by context I can tell the sentence means ''Anyhow, no matter what decision you may take, you'll still end up like this/in this situation.'' I'm just following my gut feeling though, and I'm still not sure of what that って is doing there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that sentence, 「って」 is a conjunctive particle meaning "***even if***".  Your translation is actually very good.  (It is difficult to use "even if" in the translation.)

「って」, in that context,  is synonymous to 「としても」, but 「って」 sounds much more informal than 「としても」.

> 「Phrase A + って + Phrase B」

expresses that the content of Phrase B would be the ***unexpected result*** of what the content of Phrase A might apparently suggest.